# How to set an instance attribute for all instances of a class

Tags: python-3.x, class

I have below Car class. I would like to be able to reset the mileage for all car class instances to 0. How can I do this?

```
class Car():

        carpark = []

        # initialising instance

        def __init__(self, brand, color, fuel, mileage):
            self.brand = brand
            self.color = color
            self.fuel = fuel
            self.mileage = mileage
            self.drives = []

            Car.carpark.append(self)

        @classmethod
        def purchase(cls, brand, color):
            cls(brand, color, "Diesel", 0)
```

Since I have the carpark list, i could do something like:

```
@classmethod
def reset_mileage(cls):
for car in cls.carpark:
    car.mileage = 0
```

This works but I am wondering if there is a better, cleaner way to do this?

Comment: You could create a `reset_mileage` function in the `Car` class which sets its mileage to 0. And then call that for each car in the collection. It's usually not a good idea for a class instance to control/modify the collection it is a part of.

Comment: What you have for mileage resetting seems fine to me. Generally, for questions regarding the style of working code, you might consider asking them at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Python's `property` feature to update the attributes lazily - just keep a `tick` counter on the class, and the corresponding `tick`  on each instance:

```
class Car:
   cls_mileage = 0 
   cls_mileage_tick = 0

   @classmethod
   def reset_mileage(cls, value=0):
       cls.cls_mileage = value
       cls.cls_mileage_tick = value


   def __init__(self):
       self.mileage_tick = self.cls_mileage_tick
       self.mileage = 0

   @property 
   def mileage(self):
       if self._mileage_tick < self.cls_mileage_tick:
           self._mileage_tick = self.cls_mileage_tick
           self._mileage = self.cls_mileage
       return self._mileage

   @mileage.setter
   def mileage(self, value):
       self._mileage_tick = self.cls_mileage_tick
       self._mileage = value
```

Here is some explanation on the `@property` decorator. This is some sort of "reactive pattern" on top of that. - https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property

Of course, if you need this for a lot of attributes, this pattern requires a lot of code for each one, there are ways to make this generic using the `__getattribute__` and `__setattr__` magic methods.

Also, if you can be sure of whether you are getting and setting an attribute on the instance or the class itself , there is no need for the extra `cls_` prefix on both class attributes: the names can be re-used.